# symfony ApiTestCase to tests post method

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, web-api-testing

I tried to make a simple post test api with ApiTestCase with symfony.

I tried two methods to pass the post data

```
$response = static::createClient()->request('POST', '/task/create',
        [
            'body' =>  [
                'name' => 'test',
                'description' => 'The Handmaid\'s Tale',
            ]
        ]
    );

    $response = static::createClient()->request('POST', '/task/create', ['json' => [
        'name' => 'test',
        'description' => 'The Handmaid\'s Tale',
    ]]);
```

For both exemples I got this message error

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

I know  what it is but the issue here it is like the data  wasn't sent or seen by the request, how can I resolve this issue, Thanks.

The controller to get all data in body :

```
$data = $request->request->all();
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue with empty `body`/`json`? Struggling for 4 hours already

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've already resolved it but apprarently your setter is not accepting `null`

I resolved this by changing

```
/**
     * @param string $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
```

to this

```
/**
     * @param string|null $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
```

The API testing part of Symfony is really poorly documented and contains only most primitive examples